# How to iterate two array inside React render method

Tags: reactjs-flux, reactjs

I am trying to iterate this array inside an array but its throws some error.
I am new to this React and JSX thing pls help with this.
My JSON Data is this:

```
[
  {
    "text": "Amenities",
    "type": "multi",
    "name": "amenities",
    "value": [
      {
        "text": "24 Hour Checkin",
        "id": 24,
        "disabled": true,
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "text": "Breakfast",
        "id": 23,
        "disabled": true,
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "text": "WiFi",
        "id": 22,
        "disabled": true,
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "text": "Pure Veg Restaurant",
        "id": 21,
        "disabled": true,
        "selected": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "stayType",
    "text": "Type of Stay",
    "type": "multi",
    "value": [
      {
        "text": "Hotels",
        "id": 20,
        "disabled": true,
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "text": "Lodges & Guest houses",
        "id": 19,
        "disabled": true,
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "text": "Resorts",
        "id": 18,
        "disabled": true,
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "text": "Homestays",
        "id": 19,
        "disabled": true,
        "selected": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My Script is this:

```
const React          = require('react');

const Filters = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var filtersHtml = this.state.filters.map((r, i) => {
            return (
                <ul className="section">
                    <div className="filter-heading">r.text</div>
                    if (r.type === 'multi') {
                        r.value.map((value, index) => {
                            <li className="pos-rel searchByNameTextBoxWrapper">
                                <label>{value.text}</label>
                                <input maxLength="50" value="" id={value.id} type="checkbox" className=""/>
                            </li>
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        r.value.map((obj, key) => {
                            <li className="pos-rel searchByNameTextBoxWrapper">
                                <label>{obj.text}</label>
                                <input maxLength="50" value="" id={obj.id} type="radion" className=""/>
                            </li>
                        });
                    }
                </ul>
            );
        });
        if (this.state.filters.length) {
            return (
                <div className="filters-sec-wrapper">
                    <div className="filters-inner-sec-wrapper">
                        <ul className="section">
                            {filtersHtml}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
        return (
            <div className="filters-sec-wrapper">
                <div className="filters-inner-sec-wrapper">
                    <ul className="section">
                        Loading
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Filters;
```

I tried compiling my code here https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: U r not "return"ing within map function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refactored you code, you can check it (*example below*).

```
const Filters = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { filters: this.props.filters } // just for example
  },

  isMulti: function (type) {
    return type === 'multi';
  },

  filter: function (value, type) {
    return <li key={ value.id } className="pos-rel searchByNameTextBoxWrapper">
      <label>{ value.text }</label>
      <input maxLength="50" id={ value.id } type={ type } />
    </li>;
  },  

  filters: function () {
    return this.state.filters.map((r, i) => {
      return <div key={ i }>
        <div className="filter-heading">{ r.text }</div>
        <ul className="section">
          { r.value.map((value, index) => this.filter(value, this.isMulti(r.type) ? 'checkbox' : 'radio')) } 
        </ul>
      </div>
    });
  },

  render: function () {
    var content = (this.state.filters.length) ? this.filters() : 'Loading';
    return (
      <div className="filters-sec-wrapper">
        <div className="filters-inner-sec-wrapper">{ content }</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/23343/)